# Prevent Dialog themed activity from closing onTouchOutside and onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, touch-event

I have a dialog themed activity (yes it has to be activity, not a dialog fragment or any other type of dialog due to the library's being used in this activity) anyways when my api sends a response to my client if the user doesnt have a default image this activity themed dialog pops up and I would like to make it impossible to cancel this activity themed dialog until the user uploads a photo. Currently bc the activity themed dialog is small and has a transparent background anytime a user clicks outside of the activity dialog it cancels.

**So is there any good way to PREVENT a activity themed dialog from being canceled when a user onTouchOutside or presses back?**

Answer (score 2):

What you actually have is an Activity (even if it looks like a Dialog), therefore you should call `setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)` from your activity if you want to keep it open when the background activity is clicked.

```
  Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yoptions);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
}
```

EDIT: This only works with android API level 11 or greater

And override onBackPressed() method without super() to prevent back button press.

I hope this helps ~~

Answer (score 1):

There are two way. But it works post api 11.

1. Using theme.
   Android provides attribute of theme for it.
   (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowCloseOnTouchOutside)
2. Using code.
   You can also set this attribute from code.
   (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setFinishOnTouchOutside(boolean)

Comment: Neither of which are working.In case this matters the theme im using for the activity is Sherlock.Dialog.Light

Answer (score 0):

set false for these two methods of the dialog

[SetCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29) and [setCanceledonTouchOutside](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)